# Using JavaScript, given a JSON value, recursively find all JSON objects, then sort keys in-place

Tags: javascript, sorting, json

Some background: JavaScript is not my primary language, so I'm looking to get some constructive criticism here.

I built a tiny single page HTML app that pretty prints JSON text.  It's very useful when I am looking a process logs that dump JSON without pretty printing.

In my tool, I added a checkbox to optionally sort the keys for all JSON objects.

To be clear, I am only targetting the most modern browsers, so please assume the latest and greatest of JavaScript is available.

```
function _sort_keys_deeply(json_thing)
{
    if (false === _is_sortable(json_thing))
    {
        return json_thing;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(json_thing))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < json_thing.length; ++i)
        {
            const val = json_thing[i];
            if (_is_sortable(val))
            {
                const val2 = _sort_keys_deeply(val);
                json_thing[i] = val2;
            }
        }
        return json_thing;
    }
    // else: object
    const sorted_obj = _sort_object_keys(json_thing);
    const key_arr = Object.keys(sorted_obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < key_arr.length; ++i)
    {
        const key = key_arr[i];
        const val = sorted_obj[key];
        if (_is_sortable(val))
        {
            const val2 = _sort_keys_deeply(val);
            sorted_obj[key] = val2;
        }
    }
    return sorted_obj;
}
function _is_sortable(z)
{
    // Beware: null is type object, but is not sortable.
    const x = (null !== z) && ('object' === typeof(z) || Array.isArray(z));
    return x;
}
// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102605/257299
function _sort_object_keys(obj)
{
    const key_arr = Object.keys(obj);
    // In-place array sort
    key_arr.sort();
    // Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
    const f =
        function(new_obj2, key/*, index, array*/)
        {
            new_obj2[key] = obj[key];
            return new_obj2;
        };
    const new_obj = {};
    key_arr.reduce(f, new_obj);
    return new_obj;
}
```

Comment: `Array.sort()` can sort `null` if done so explicitly in a `compareFunction` passed into `sort()`. [See MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/sort)

Comment: `false === _is_sortable(json_thing)` -> left-handed boolean comparison! ... 15 yr dormant PTSD nightmares returning! A former C programmer? Nostalgia? Seriously, just curious why. Has ES5 or beyond not fixed the need for this? The world wonders

Comment: @radarbob Fair question.  Previously, I worked with finance quants.  In a shared code-base, we stopped using the not operator (!) because it was too easy to miss in very dense formulas.  Instead, we switched to explicit left-side boolean testing which was (is!) horribly ugly, but much harder to miss.  Over the long term, I found it helped to reduce boolean logic bugs, so I kept doing it in other situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code was well-commented and easy enough to figure out.  Well done on that front.

Stylistic notes:

- In JS it's idiomatic to use `camelCase`, not `snake_case`.
- This code is formatted like C# code.  In JS, open brace on same line is more common.
- Feel free to leave out the semi-colons.

Design notes:

- You can make the small helper functions one-liners and define them *within* the main function.  This way, conceptually, you'll be writing a single function to solve a single problem.
- In my rewrite below, I've left off the braces on the single-statement `if`s.  That's a personal preference but makes some people uneasy.  Feel free to add them back.

Here is my attempt at a rewrite based on these notes.  Let me know if I've unwittingly changed any behavior:

```
function sorted(o) {
  const isObj = x => typeof(x) === 'object'
  const isArr = Array.isArray

  // Beware: null is type object, but is not sortable.
  const isSortable = x => (x !== null) && (isObj(x) || isArr(x))

  if (!isSortable(o))
    return o

  if (isArr(o))
    return o.map(sorted)

  if (isObj(o))
    return Object.keys(o).sort().reduce(
      (m, x) => (m[x] = isSortable(o[x]) ? sorted(o[x]) : o[x], m),
      {}
    )
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELzzFZNLYksEqenNEq36BTn0GOVgg1NBACNjKhDh2@kakgblYu9jdnZncvkrm8RmtdsrqXSxr0yqp@nSVonLTIXGWKdTZjiGAEhM1ThkzVHliNEh/oDra20urOOI4xg7o3KduN0K@2UtYemVfTRnsl91v4lfqkI/6FiHDfFUbVFwbLdg8zJPf7stZBTzgBiyC9jmSUAncqoCVrvWVjAPzDL02o1KWbNFHH8i/aoX5HEWFF1131Ar8iOMR1anbaLZDARYGcIbQOeXp@5MWtZ3UYXj89/JORXwf4iSh3eOYZwDHoxBQE5ggBKHEFK8hUgEBqUEKJRSHMYQqcCJsuFeFPDF9/MYeF9NoaPC/Nzleb@m6Q8)

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing refactoring.  Very elegant.  Thank you to teach.  My only concern is the assignment + test in the same expression: `(m, x) => (m[x] = isSortable(o[x]) ? ...`  Those are a bit dangerous in my experience!

Comment: Thanks.  I know some people don't like ternaries, but my rule is that as long as they aren't nested, each branch is a simple expression, and they fit comfortably on one line, they are a good thing.  That said, if you don't agree you can rewrite like so: (cont)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHLboMwELzzFZNLYksEqenNEpH6BTn0GOVgg1ORGhwZU4EI307XQB5qfbDWM@Px7vgif2SdueLqt0oqbbaVzfU4npsq84WtUFvndc4sRx8Bma1qj6I@qAtStEj38N1V2zNrOdI0xcaqi8785kX74RxpaZddMp1k98J@kr9URt/tWIsV@VSNMRzrNdj0WLC/3WYzqnlEDsUZbPU0oBY5oYDTvnEV7F0zX/rLJqW8snk4/lSGp/4oD9NAybfuaqKScIXxxOm8yTSbhAArY4QA9lNI85oNn90d29NiPK@SABr6nm@gH6w2tf4vDZoHunRXLsAQL0U/TAWPhiiiQNFDiV0MKd5iZAK9UgJUSil2Q4xc4EinfgEFAvh@GqLwPdboxNivJaUQ@zj@Ag "JavaScript (Babel Node) – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, I checked your second link: Wow, the ternary really makes a difference!  I guess I will keep it and add a comment to the code "beware".  :-)

Comment: *... formatted like C#* ::  Line breaking a JS statement with a "dangling operator" (opening brace, boolean operator, etc.)  prevents possible JS mis-interpretation.  [And no one seems to use explicit " ; " anymore](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/codebyte-why-are-explicit-semicolons-important-in-javascript-49550bea0b82/). I've been bitten by these at one time or another.

Comment: I was referring to the open brace on own line with the C# comment.  As for semi-colons, the examples in that article are silly imo.  The 2nd example is something you wouldn't ever write, and the 1st is something very few people would ever do by mistake.  It's [perfectly fine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qlr-FGbhKaI&t=13s) to leave them out, and I recommend doing so.

Comment: up-ed for formatting and ternary use. Here, testing exceptional cases up front erases complexity such that code reading and understanding shines from good formatting. Surrounding control blocks with whitespace is essential IMO.  Brace-less one liner `if`s are elegant *and definitely aid quick understanding*. The ternary's beauty is it's counterintuitive understandability. With *disciplined formatting*, control logic is spatial expressed and even nesting, 1 deep anyway, can manifest this property.  Nothing here is absolute.

Answer (score 1):

### JSON

JSON is a not a thing, it is a transport file format, held in memory as a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
In JavaScript it is parsed using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and the result is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).
To refer to an object as a `json_thing` is incorrect (yes its a "thing")  but it's  not a string or blob formatted to as JSON.

The only thing that makes an object unique when created from a JSON string is that you are guaranteed not to have cyclic references.

### General notes.

There is a lot of code noise in your code. Code noise is anything that does not contribute to the algorithm process

You modify the array in place, but you copy objects. Best if you treat arrays and objects the same, either in place or as a copy. The rewrites give examples of both

### Call stack overflow

JavaScript uses a call stack (as do most languages) unfortunately almost all JavaScript implementations do not recognize tail calls (even though its part of the ECMAScript6 standard) meaning that recursion is dangerous.

There is no way to know how deep the call stack is, nor how deep you must go to complete the task. Always be wary of this when creating recursive code.

The rewrites gives an example of a non recursive solution that can process a much deeper object than a recursive function can.

### Code style

- Declare variable at top of function as this is where variables declared as [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) are created. Function declaration (eg `function name(){}`) are also hoisted to the top of their scope in JavaScript.

  **Note** that [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) are block scope `{/*block*/}` and are not hoisted to the top of their scope. You can not use them before they are declared.
- If you don't need the index use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) of loop rather than a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

  **Note** Using callback iterators can add overhead to processing and are generals slower than for loops.
- Avoid single use variables unless they help keep the code clean.
- JavaScript logical operators always execute in the same order (unlike C/C++) and can thus be used to reduce code noise via short circuit syntax style. Eg `if (foo) { foo = 0 }` can be `foo && (foo = 0);`

  **Note** that the `()` around the second (3rd etc...) logical clause is required if there is an assignment operator within a short circuit expression.

  **Note** you can not short circuit flow control eg `foo && return` is illegal. Same for `break`, `continue`, `if`, `for` etc...

  As the order of logical and grouped expressions / statements is always the same you can optimize them using most likely outcome. eg testing `z !== null && typeof z === "object"` can be optimized as `typeof z === "object" && z !== null` as it is far more likely that z is not an object than it being `null`
- Use the short form/style when you can. Eg `if (false === isSortable(obj)) {` can be `if (!isSortable(obj)) {`
- Function arguments are function scoped and writeable (almost identical to `var`). Reuse them if it helps reduce code noise.
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) works on [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), and [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) thus you do not need to treat object and array separately.
- Array is a `typeof` `"object"`. The `Array.isArray` in `isSortable` is redundant.

  Note that [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a JavaScript operator and not a function. `typeof(z)` is the same as `typeof z` the grouping operator has no effect in this case
- You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object from an array of key, name pairs. `Object.fromEntries([["A", 1], ["B", 2]])` will define an object `{A:1, B:1}`

### Rewrite

Rewrite removes the code noise and redundant code.

I have provided three versions.

1. uses recursion and creates a copy of objects that are sorted. This rewrite is the only one the matches you function`s behavior
2. uses a stack and sorts object keys in place. Only arrays and object are pushed to the stack.
3. Same as 2 but checks for cyclic references and as such is the only rewrite safe to use.

**NOTE** ONLY use the first two on objects that do not have cyclic references. The recursive example will throw an error very quickly, the second will need to use up memory before it has a problem (this will lock the page as it chews up memory), and then depending on the engine could crash the page/thread or throw an error.

#### Recursive

```
function sortKeysDeeply(obj) {
    if (isObj(obj)) {
        !Array.isArray(obj) && (obj = sortObjectKeys(obj));
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(sorted)) {
            isObj(val) && (obj[key] = sortKeysDeeply(val));
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

#### Using a stack

```
function sortKeysDeeply(obj) {
    const stack = [];
    if (isObj(obj)) {
        stack.push(obj);
        while (stack.length) {
            let o = stack.pop();
            o = !Array.isArray(o) && sortInPlaceObjectKeys(o);
            for (const val of Object.values(o)) { isObj(val) && stack.push(val) }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

#### Cyclic safe stack

This uses a [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) to track which object references have been encountered.

A week set only holds the generated hash rather than the object and thus uses a little less memory than [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and reduces the GC workload.

You can use this in the recursive code as well.

```
function sortKeysDeeply(obj) {
    const stack = [], checked = new WeakSet();
    if (isObj(obj)) {
        stack.push(obj);
        while (stack.length) {
            let o = stack.pop();
            checked.add(o);
            o = !Array.isArray(o) && sortInPlaceObjectKeys(o);
            for (const val of Object.values(o)) { 
                isObj(val) && !checked.has(val) && stack.push(val);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

#### Helper functions

Function required by above rewrites.

```
const strSorter = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
const isObj = obj => 'object' === typeof(obj) && null !== obj;
const sortObjectKeys = obj => 
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => strSorter(a[0], b[0])));
        
const sortInPlaceObjectKeys = obj => {
    const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => strSorter(a[0], b[0]));
    for (const [key] of sorted) { delete obj[key] }
    return Object.assign(obj, Object.fromEntries(sorted));
}
```